# How do programs ensure the port they are listening to is not already in use?

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm just curious about this, but I know there is a range of ports that programs can use, but I'm curious how do they know that the port they are listening to isn't already in use by another program? After all it seems like the port number is chosen at random, there is always a chance of a clash happening. And if a clash does occur, what happens?

Comment: have you tried connecting to it? plus hello neighbour, you are the user who registered directly before me.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers, applications, and OSes are off-topic here.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson Hi there! I didn't connect to it because I don't know how to. I'm not doing any sort of networking or whatsoever. I just happen to come across this topic and got curious. And since I couldn't find any answers online, I asked StackExchange. :)

Comment: try telnet for connecting to the port you want to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport layer port numbers are managed by the respective protocol (usually within the OS's stack). Before an application can use any specific port it needs to allocate it. Failing that, it simply can't use it.

For outbound connections, most applications allocate an ephemeral port (49,152 onwards, on Linux often 32,768 onwards). The numbers may look random.

Comment: Regarding outbound connections, the Wikipedia page on *ephemeral ports* has a lot of great links.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port